# Which version of OpenCV should I use for pure C language projects

Tags: c, opencv

I would like to write pure OpenCV/C projects. I'm aware of the fact that the newest OpenCV versions are C++ wrapper of C which support C language, however, the first versions of OpenCV are pure C libraries. My question is in case targeting pure C projects like embedded projects, should I stick with the old versions like opencv-1.0.0 in case using pure C compilers?

Comment: You'd better use another library... like cimg. It's a bad idea to use an obsolete version, or its deprecated functions

Comment: @Miki, I've took a look at it but it says "The CImg Library is a small, open-source, and modern C++ toolkit for image processing,". Are you sure I can utilize c compilers?

Comment: Sorry I got confused... I meant libccv